# Moving country.

Tags: itunes, itunes-match, billing

I have recently moved country and want to change my billing info over as a result.

Before I left I took out a subscription to iTunes Match, and did not bring my laptop with me as it was wiped and sold so my music is not physically stored on any machine.

Is there any way I can change over the country on my account without losing all the music I have in the cloud storage as it is asking me to cancel my subscription before this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to change the country before downloading all music?

If not, just connect to your account, download your music, copy it out of the default folder (to make sure). Then update your account details, and if needed re-upload all your music.

Answer (score 0):

When I moved abroad I asked Apple whether I **must** change my Apple ID location to that other country.  From what I understand from their reply, it is not necessary nor mandatory.

However if I were to change the location it would indeed imply some serious changes.  Now 3 years later, I've been using my US Apple ID abroad without any issue.

This was Apple's reply:

> This is xxxxx from iTunes Store Support and I'll be glad to be your
>   Advisor for today. Rest assured you will have my personal and prompt
>   attention to this matter.
>
> I understand that you have questions with your Apple ID as you will be
>   moving from San Francisco to xxxxxxxxxx. I will try to answer you
>   inquiries to the best of my ability.
>
> For your first question if would need to change the country associated
>   with your account, that would be your decision. You have the options
>   to change the country associated with your account and use the same
>   Apple ID or you can just create another account that you can use for
>   xxxxxxxxxx iTunes Store.
>
> If you decided to change the country associated with your account and
>   use the same account, let me provide these reminders before doing so:
>
> 1) If you have store credit, you must use the credit before you can
>   change countries.
>
> 2) You will need to download all purchased content. In addition,
>   rented items must be past their 30-day expiration. For more
>   information on rentals, please see:
>
> http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1657
>
> 3) You must provide a payment method, such as a credit or debit card
>   associated with a valid billing address in the new country. An iTunes
>   Store Gift Card issued in the new country is also an acceptable
>   payment method.
>
> 4) After you change countries, you will no longer receive application
>   update notifications in iTunes for the apps you purchased in your
>   original country. However, you'll still receive update notifications
>   on your iOS device for any applications installed on it.
>
> 5) If you have an iTunes Match subscription, you can't change
>   countries until the subscription has expired.
>
> 6) If you have purchased a Season Pass, you cannot change the country
>   associated with your account until that season is done airing and the
>   last episode of the season has been added to the iTunes Store.
>
> 7) If you have been using iTunes in the Cloud to download past
>   purchases from your Purchased page, these purchases will no longer
>   appear when you change the country.